# Fresh install of Eclipse Mars won't run

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-14.04, java, eclipse-mars

Currently running Elementary OS (Ubuntu 14.04). I am able to install and run eclipse 4.4 (Luna), but after unpacking the 4.5 tar my machine crashes after the splash screen. I can't check my workspace/.metadata logs because a workspace is not created before the crash. Have tried with Java 8 from the webupd8 ppa, Java 8 from Oracle, and the openjdk-7 from the Ubuntu repos. Also tried the Eclipse installer to have the same problem, crashing after the splash screen.

Where else could I look for issues?

Comment: 64 bit or 32 bit Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

### GTK3 and Pantheon

Turns out the problem was with my DE (Pantheon) and GTK3 menus.

[Here's the bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=465107)

So if we disable gtk3 either with:

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

before running eclipse
or write a short script found [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2014/02/21/using-eclipse-luna-on-ubunbu/)

```
#!/bin/bash
export SWT_GTK3=0
export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0
./eclipse -showlocation
```

With The GTK menus disabled, eclipse runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the virtual machine in the `eclipse.ini` file. e.g.:

```
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
```

Comment: Tried this, specifying the java-8 Runtime. Same error occurs